# DIALOG DOWNLOAD PROGRESS always shows 100% on second download attempt

Tags: android, dialog, webview, download

I need help here, my DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS always shows 100% on onPreExecute() (Second Download Attempt). How to make it start from 0% from the second attempt download. Need help here. Thanks

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:

        return null;
    }
}
```

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

....

```
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `onCreateDialog` is called only once to create the dialog, you'll have to reset the dialog in `onPrepareDialog` which is called every time before the dialog is shown.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) 
    if (id == DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS)
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

        switch(id){

            case 0:

                _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(null);


                _progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading files..");

                _progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

                _progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Hide", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "hide");

                    }

                });

                _progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "cancel");

                        cancelLoad();

                    }

                        private void cancelLoad() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                });

        }

        return _progressDialog;

    }
```

Comment: Here is the code that I have worked for DIALOGUE DOWNLOAD PROGRESS, but no dialog appears, do not know what the problem is I pray you who can help me to tell what the problem is why dialogue is not displayed.